# Borders of the districts in google map using asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, google-maps

Is there any code for border's of the district in a map. I am using asp.net pages, can you help me, i did small map app the code is

```
    <script type="text/javascript"    
     src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api  /js?key=AIzaSyDY0kkJiTPVd2U7aTOAwhc9ySH6oHxOIYM&sensor=false">      
    </script>
 <script type="text/javascript">

var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850);

function initialize()
 {
  var mapProp = {
 center: myCenter,
  zoom:5,
 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myCenter,
  title:'Click to zoom'
   });

   marker.setMap(map);

  // Zoom to 9 when clicking on marker
   google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',function() {
    map.setZoom(9);
     map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
     });
     }
     google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
   </script>

   <div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>
```

But i want the code which shoe the district borders/state borders like that can you help me.